# Magento2: I have an error running the command setup:static-content:deploy

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.2.3, static-content-deploy

I have a Magento 2.2.3, I get the error below after running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

This error only gives me when my custom theme makes fallback in the **Magento/luma** theme if I make fallback to the **Magento/blank** theme, it works.

My custom theme has two `theme.xml` and`registration.php` files.

```
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(189): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('images/select-b...', Array)
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(136): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(107): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service\{closure}()
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(186): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(108): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure))
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(281): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deploy(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array)
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(200): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->execute(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(162): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->assertAndExecute('frontend/Comaxx...', Array, Array)
#12 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Strategy/QuickDeploy.php(76): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->process()
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticContent.php(109): Magento\Deploy\Strategy\QuickDeploy->deploy(Array)
#14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(140): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent->deploy(Array)
#15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(241): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(843): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(193): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(104): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projects/Magento/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#21 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed in the version of Magento 2.2.4.

It must upgrade of Magento version.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a common problem and it's can be for different case.

The best things will be if you debug.

Suppose in my case.

vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php

$this->deployStaticFile->deployFile()

method.

As that is on core so i did put try cache and got my solution.

For Example :

```
    $this->deployStaticFile->deployFile(
        $file->getFileName(),
        [
            'area' => $package->getArea(),
            'theme' => $package->getTheme(),
            'locale' => $package->getLocale(),
            'module' => $file->getModule(),
        ]
    );
```

code changed to

```
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test-exception.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            try {
                $this->deployStaticFile->deployFile(
                    $file->getFileName(),
                    [
                        'area' => $package->getArea(),
                        'theme' => $package->getTheme(),
                        'locale' => $package->getLocale(),
                        'module' => $file->getModule(),
                    ]
                );
            }catch (\Exception $exception) {
                $logger->info("Exception FOUND");
                $logger->info($exception);
            }
```

Then found my exception and --

In my case there was an unexpected symlink in my code and when it try to copy the error happen.

After fixing please revert the code.