# getting errors when running setup:static-content:deploy -f magento 2.2.8

Tags: static-content-deploy, magento2.2.8

I am trying install a new theme in magento 2.2.8 and when i run in terminal `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` 
This is the error that appear:

```
#0 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#2 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(92): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#3 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(189): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('js/owl.carousel...', Array)
#4 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(136): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#5 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(107): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(186): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/State/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure), Array)
#9 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(108): Magento\Framework\App\State\Interceptor->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(300): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deploy(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array)
#11 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(219): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->execute(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#12 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(162): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->assertAndExecute('frontend/danisa...', Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Strategy/QuickDeploy.php(76): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->process()
#14 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticContent.php(109): Magento\Deploy\Strategy\QuickDeploy->deploy(Array)
#15 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(140): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent->deploy(Array)
#16 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(245): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(835): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(185): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(102): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /var/www/clients/client19/web982/web/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#22 {main}
```

Comment: Please run command and see in which mode you are on `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`

Comment: Remove generate and var folder after run deploy commamd.

Comment: @saifzakir mode is default .

Comment: @vishalbaraiya I deleted the folder var and generated but still the error persist.

Comment: ok please check your theme is the support of Magento 2.2.8 version and remove adminhtml and frontend in pub static folder after run deploys command.

Comment: check this link may similar issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231659/magento2-i-have-an-error-running-the-command-setupstatic-contentdeploy

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to help me with this issue. The problem was caused from a file of the template that was incomplete in folder app/code/themexxx , and i updated the magento version to 2.3.2 .